# How to make 16 coin vibration motors and 5 servos work at the same time on a Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, pins, current

I saw in Arduino Mega's datasheet that the sum of currents out of all input/output pins combined should be maximum 200mA. But I want to make 16 vibration motors and 5 servos work together on the same time. I made the circuit(NMOS, flyback diode, etc.) for every coin vibration motor.Also I'm thinking to power the servos with an external power source.Are the circuits enough so i dont pass the 200mA limit? How can I make the whole thing work together?
im using the following components:

1. [NMOS](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF)
2. [coin vibration motor](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/310-101_datasheet.pdf)
3. [servo motor](https://components101.com/motors/mg90s-metal-gear-servo-motor)

Comment: You never power motors with an IO pin. All you ever do is send a tiny signal to the controller for the motor, whatever that is for the type of motor you are controlling.

Comment: I'm sorry for my english if i didn't put it down correctly. I'm actually using this circuit [link](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/how-to-drive-a-vibration-motor-with-arduino-and-genuino/). Do you mean that if i do that for all 16 motors i will be ok with this? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard motor circuit (except there should be some snubber circuit across the motor). Like I said - you don't power the motors with the IO pin. You just send a tiny signal. The current of the motors is irrelevant, and the current of the signal is minuscule. You'd be lucky to total 1mA.

Comment: But how is 1mA even possible?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean, how is it "possible"?

Comment: I think its too low. Isn't it? I saw that every IO pin draw 35mA.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the word "limit"?

Comment: I tried with a multimeter to measure the IO current draw and it seems that i draw 35mA. Maybe I'm measuring the wrong way. Where should i put the probes to measure correctly?

Comment: Current is drawn by a device. The probes should be in series with the device drawing the current.

Comment: Thank you for your help!